# Gradient wrt a parameter of a parametrized integral

Tags: integration, vector-analysis, subgradient

I am unable to understand how the operator is taken out of the integral. Is this some standard practice?

$$
\begin{aligned}
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \nabla_{\theta} p(y ; \theta) d y \\
&=\nabla_{\theta} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} p(y ; \theta) d y \\
&=0
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 0):

The operator is the gradient with respect to $\theta$, while the integral is with respect to $y$, so this is valid as long as the two variables are independent. For more information see the Leibniz integral rule.

Comment: y is parametrized by theta, so there are dependent right?

Comment: How is $y$ parametrised by $\theta $?